# some solution to start the instance

Tags: anycast

The [start] operation type failed with the message "The zone 'projects / meta-view-335220 / zones / europe-west4-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Please try a different zone or retry try again later. "

Yesterday I stopped the instance, and today I wanted to start it but it seems like this, what do I do? I have read that some people used to erase the disk but I don't want to lose it all, any solution?

Comment: Please ask your question in English.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Cloud provider, instance type, reservations, etc? Normally this kind of error would indicate an issue with the cloud provider - on AWS you'd get something like this if there wasn't enough capacity to launch your instance, and you'd have to try changing the type of instance or launching in a different zone to overcome it.